# Azure connection string is ignored

Tags: azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I have an `AppService` deployed and running on `Azure`. It connects to a `Google Cloud PostreSQL` database and have no problems.
In order to remove the connection string from the `appSettings.config`, I want to use an `Azure` connection string, which ***should*** override the `appSettings.config` value. I wrote ***should*** because I did it, but the value set in `Azure` is completely ignored.
This is my appSettings:

```
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "postgres": "Host=XX.XX.XXX.XXX;Database=production;Username=portal;Password=myPassword"
  }
}
```

As I mentioned before, it is running. IF I add a value `postgres` with value `"Host=XX.XX.XXX.XXX;Database=production;Username=portal;Password=wrongPassword"`, it still works, even if it souldn't.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found the @ [jan-hernandez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11529321/jan-hernandez) solution which can help to fix your issue.

To connect `Google Cloud SQL/PostgreSQL` of google you need to **enable** the `Public IP` of your **Database** and **whitelist** the `Public IP` of your **Azure app** to Allow connections between Azure app and Cloud SQL/PostgreSQL

The only way to connect to `Cloud SQL/PostgreSQL` from the external services is via IP connection in this [document](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/sqlserver/configure-ip#add) is explained step by step how to enable Public IP for your SQL server and how to whitelist the incoming IP addresses.

Refer this [article](https://forums.asp.net/t/1937265.aspx?how%20to%20access%20SQL%20server%20using%20Public%20IP) about how to create a connection string using public IP

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60870081/15997690)

Comment: But I don't have problems to connect. As I wrote `I have no problems`, my problem is I'm not able to override che connection string.